# Linq to SQL over zealous serialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, json, linq-to-sql, serialization

Im developing an API using .NET MVC and returning results in JSON format. At first it seemed to work ok with my results returned from the database as IEnumerable which are then converted to JSONResult type to be returned.

This serializes the hierrachy for me and child objects are loaded automaticaly based on relationships in the designer and become part of a JSON hierrachy.

```
IEnumerable<Book> books= _contentRepository.GetBooks();

return Json(new {
                   success = true,
                   data = new {
                                 books = books
                              }
                }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This power is also the problem as sometimes a whole load of child objects are loaded which I dont need. For example, say I've got a book entity which has related books and these related books also have related books, the tree gets very deep very quickly.

Rick Strahl talks about this towards the end of his article: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/147218.aspx

I still want to keep a hierrachy, so that the json is also hierrachical. e.g. book.author, book.publisher[0].name but I want some control over what is loaded in the query.

Am I looking at removing all the links between entities in the designer and specifying joins in the query or queries and possibly manually making up the resulting hierrachy?

Answer (score 1):

I would use a view model: a class which is specifically tailored to meet the requirements of the view (or in your case the JSON structure). Then have the controller action [map](http://automapper.codeplex.com/) between the model which is fetched from the database and the view model. Now you have full control.

```
IEnumerable<Book> books = _contentRepository.GetBooks();
IEnumerable<BookViewModel> bookViewModels = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Book>, IEnumerable<BookViewModel>>(books);
return Json(
    new { success = true, data = bookViewModels }, 
    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
);
```

Comment: This works great to ensure only the desired data is returned (are you using Automapper) but the unneeded data is loaded in the first place, and could slow things down) as child collections of the main object...

Answer (score 0):

How are you loading related objects automatically?  Normally those collections are deferred EntitySet instances, which aren't loaded if they aren't enumerated.  Are you sure you have the problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: My repository method is returning IEnumerable<T> which contains all the child objects as well, unless I mark the relationship as internal in the dbml...